# Pb initializing ModelForm

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django, and I have a problem with ModelForm. So I have an app which is named *mini_url*. In this app I have a model :

```
class MiniURL(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(unique=True)
    code = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, verbose_name='Date de création')
    pseudo = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    nb_acces = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I wanted to create a form based on my model, so I did this in a *form.py* file :

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from mini_url.models import MiniURL


def MiniURLForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MiniURL
        fields = ['url', 'pseudo']
```

And then in my view I have this :

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from mini_url.models import MiniURL


def create_url(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MiniURLForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_url = MiniURL()
            new_url.url = form.cleaned_data['url']
            new_url.pseudo = form.cleaned_data['pseudo']
            new_url.code = generer(5)
            new_url.save()

    else:
        form = MiniURLForm()

    return render(request, 'mini_url/create_url.html', {'form': form})
```

Finally my template (*mini_url/create_url.html*) which shows the form :

```
<p>
    <form action="{% url "mini_url.views.create_url" %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
</p>
```

But when I try to acceed to the template I have this error :

```
MiniURLForm() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ModelForm'
```

And it shows me that the error is in my view at the line where there is :

```
form = MiniURLForm()
```

So I don't understand why it fails. I did what the doc says I think : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#topics-forms-modelforms

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: Titles are not character-limited; you have a problem, not a pb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have accidentally defined `MiniURLForm` as a function instead of a form class.

Change

```
def MiniURLForm(ModelForm): # wrong
```

to

```
class MiniURLForm(ModelForm): # should be a class
```

When you defined `MiniURLForm` as a function, Django expected  a positional argument as per your definition. Change it to a form class and it should work correctly.

**Final Code:**

```
class MiniURLForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MiniURL
        fields = ['url', 'pseudo']
```

Comment: Oh yeah, exact. Thank you ! I thought I created a class, but it was a function ahah